# Searching trough column (cells from 2 to 1001) and comparing date in every cell to extract data from the same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm fighting with my spreadsheet for over an hour and cannot find the right solution.
I have table like this:

```
 A          B           C
REQ      some info    date
REQ      some info    date
REQ      some info    date
```

In some other cell I want to display REQ number if the date cell matches today's date so I'm trying to create function which searches column C from 2 to 1001 for today's date and if the value matches I want to extract data from A column of the same row to my other table in the same sheet.

I tried nesting VLOOKUP and INDIRECT with IF but so far I didn't succeed.

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(TODAY();$C$2:$C$1001;1;FALSE)=($C$2:$C$1001=TODAY()); A156; "No Data")
```

I don't know how to handle variable cells in Excel functions, it'll search from 2 to 1001 but lets say it will find today's date in row 326 in column C so I want copy the data from the row 326 column A and here lies the problem - I don't know how to use variable found cell in my function.

Is there some simpler solution to this problem?

Comment: You might wanna research about `INDEX`/`MATCH`. Can there be multiple matches? Some sample data is always nice have.

Comment: You need `FILTER()` function if you have `Office365`. Alternatively `INDEX()` and `AGGREGATE()` together.

Answer (score 0):

VLOOKUP is only going to search the first column so you could solve this by reorganizing your columns.

If you swap columns 1 and 3 you can use the VLOOKUP like this

```
=VLOOKUP(TODAY(),A2:C1001,3,FALSE)
```

Another way to get this is to find the row number that matches your date adding 1 for the column header

```
MATCH(TODAY(),C2:C1001,0)+1
```

Then lookup the value in column 1 for that same row

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(TODAY(),C2:C1001,0)+1,1))
```